# Best practice for HTML building in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Long story short, this right here seems incredibly wonky to me (not the actual code but the way it's written):

```
var B_ProgressBar = '<span style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:#FFFFFF;width:100px;display:inline-block;" onmouseover="PBtext'
+ int + '.innerHTML=\'' + chaptersremaining + "/" + chapterstotal + '\';PBgreen' + int + '.style.width=\'' + chppercent + '%\'" onmouseout="PBtext'
+ int + '.innerHTML=\'' + Npercentage + '%\';PBgreen' + int + '.style.width=\'' + Npercentage + '%\'"><span id="PBgreen' + int
+ '" style="background-color:#01CA24;width:' + Npercentage + '%;display:inline-block;"><span id="PBtext' + int + '" style="display:inline-block;">'
+ Npercentage + '%</span></span></span>';
```

Lots of + and lots of escaped quotation marks.

I come from a Java world, where overuse of string concatenation is usually the last thing you want.

Yet it's the only solution I can think of for JS. I know frameworks like AngularJS and possibly jQuery take the nastiness out of such disgusting code using templates and inject the proper code without having to worry about missing a closing pointy bracket at some point.

Doesn't JS have some built-in functionality to build HTML blocks without having to resort to third party libraries? Something like an "Hypertext builder", which allows one to pass a couple parameters into a mask and the function spits out a nice, ready to use div block or something.

Think of prepared statements for SQL or printf() in C.

Comment: Can't you just use `createElement` and append to it/make it a child as needed?

Comment: [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) is widely used. You can learn a lot from its implementation.

Comment: I'm going to suggest using a data binding library like knockout.  I know you didn't want to use a 3rd party library so this isn't really an answer, but knockout is very lightweight and lets you directly bind HTML elements to Javascript objects without doing ugly string concatenation, and even without doing any DOM operations.  The tutorial http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro gives you a good idea of what's available in an hour or so.

Comment: it is wonky. Why do you need to generate HTML elements dynamically? From the looks of your sample code yoou have a progress bar where you are trying to dynamically adjust the width `Npercentage`. There are lots of ways to accomplish that without injecting raw HTML into the DOM

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. The **DOM (Document Object Model)** is an API served for exactly this purpose.

As a first step, look into the following functions:

- [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)
- [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

These will allow you to create HTML elements, and append them to the DOM.

For more reading on the **DOM, an essential subject to understand in Web development**, read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Last point I would recommend is to read MDN over W3 Schools, if you want an in depth analysis on how an API in JS works!

Comment: I'm curous about you advising against W3. Not that I have a problem with that, I'm genuinely curious, as I've always used it.

Comment: Selbi - w3 schools is great if you want a quick overview of what something does. MDN gives you real in-depth analysis, with a lot more relevant links. I'll update my comment, to not completely hate on something, which I have used many times!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript supports [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and
not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

I would lean towards using DOM Manipulation and using `createElement` and friends rather then generating raw HTML though.